# Unique prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, big-list

This is a question out of curiosity. For example:

- $2$ is the ONLY even prime number.
- $5$ is the ONLY prime number whose last (or only) digit is $5$.
- $73$ is the ONLY  prime number which satisfies both the product property and the mirror property ([Shledon prime](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Sheldon_Prime)).

My question is, do you know other prime numbers that have unique properties?

Comment: By that standard, they're all unique, $3$ is the only prime number divisible by $3$ etc. We don't know this for sure, but the Fermat primes may be a finite and thus unique set. You may find lots to interest you here: https://primes.utm.edu/curios/

Comment: @AlexK What is a "unique set" and in what sense is an infinite set not "unique" ?

Comment: So, the purpose is to find nontrivial properties that are satisfied by onle one prime number ?

Comment: @Peter I mean unique in a colloquial sense -- if it's finite, the property is unique to its several members, and they fit a pretty unusual but recognizable pattern.

Comment: It is in fact unknown whether there are finite many Fermat primes, but chances are extremely good that $2^{16}+1$ is the largest.

Comment: I think this rather falls into the argument that there are no uninteresting naturals numbers; there are also no uninteresting primes. The argument is simple: make a list of all of the interesting naturals. This gives us a set of the uninteresting naturals. But this set has a smallest element, and surely the "smallest uninteresting naturals" is an interesting property to have! But if we then say this smallest element is interesting, the uninteresting numbers now have a new smallest element. By induction, the cardinality of the uninteresting numbers is zero.

Comment: And then of course we have to debate what is or is not a "property." $79$ is the smallest prime number associated with a well-known volcanic eruption, for instance.

Comment: 57 is the Grothendieck prime, https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6358/story-of-grothendiecks-prime-number

Comment: @EricSnyder This is a well-known joke proof (of course not an actually valid proof). But I agree that "property" has to be specified , otherwise every prime $p$ has the property to be the largest prime $p$ not exceeding $p$ or other extremely boring properties.

Answer (score 1):

The Prime Number 73939133 is also an interesting prime number. If you remove each digit from the right it is still a prime number every time. It is the largest number known to exhibit such property

Comment: It's not just the largest known, it's the largest there is. See https://oeis.org/A127890

Comment: It is not even difficult to show this.

Comment: What's the longest one in any reasonably small base? Is there any base where you could have an infinite progression like this?

Comment: @AlexK My guess is that there are only finite such prime numbers in any base. But no idea whether this can be proven.

Comment: @Alex, the largest in various bases is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A023107 along with references to the literature. Why not have a look at the literature, and then report back to us on what you find?

Comment: @Alex, have you followed up?

Comment: Not as far as the literature, no. The series seems to grow with $10^n$, which is interesting in its own right, given that it's not tied to base 10. It develops a hint of a pattern near 100.